# asp.net login function to database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hello i want to make a log in function in asp.net but i have no clue on what to do. i have taken the login toolbox and place it, what do i do next

```
  void Fillcombo() {
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;username=username;password=password";
        string Query = "select * from hotel";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
```

and here is the login

```
 protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Start by connecting to the database. Simply dragging and dropping from the toolbox isn't going to create functionality.

Comment: i have that in   void Fillcombo() {
            string constring = "datasource=localhost;username=username;password=password";
            string Query = "select * from hotel";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            try

Comment: Can you add that code to your original question so it formats it appropriately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to build onto **Nasir's** earlier response with a simple database routine.

I have written this using SQL Server, so some translation may be needed. I have written this based on the saved password has been hashed. **Hashing is your responsibility!**

```
private bool IsAuthenticate(string username,string password) {
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;username=username;password=password";
    string Query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM hotel WHERE (UserLogin = @UserLogin) AND (UserPassword = @UserPassword)";
    int RecordsMatched;

    string UserLogin = username;
    string UserPassword = SomeHashFunction(password)

    using (SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring)) {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase)) {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserLogin", UserLogin);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPassword", UserPassword);

            try {
                conDataBase.Open();
                RecordsMatched = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                RecordsMatched = -1;
                Console.Write(ex);
                // your error handling here
            }
            finally {
                conDataBase.Close();
                // your cleanup here
            }
        }
    }
    // Logic for RecordsMatched
    // -1: An error occurred
    //  0: UserLogin and/or UserPassword did not match
    //  1: Authenticated
    // 2+: You have multiple users with same credentials

    return (RecordsMatched == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    string userName = Login1.UserName;
    string password = Login1.Password;

    bool result = IsAuthenticate(userName, password);
    if ((result))
    {
        e.Authenticated = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }

}

protected bool IsAuthenticate(string username,string password)
{
    // implement this method according to your database..

}
```